# Numbers required to represent all non-linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-analysis

According to Linear Algebra, all linear transformations from $R^2$ to $R^2$ can be represented by a 2-by-2 matrix $A \in R^{2x2}$. Essentially, four real numbers (i.e., the entries of the table) are all that is required to represent all linear transformation in this space.

Note: Probably complex numbers also need to be accounted for in the above.

So what is the case for **all** transformations from $R^2$ to $R^2$ (both linear and non-linear) ? Is it possible to use $n$ numbers to represent all these transformations, as was done with 4 numbers for linear transformations?

Comment: No.  Linearity is very special.

Comment: In general, functions live in infinite-dimensional space, so probably the best thing you can do is express some transformations in terms of Taylor series for matrix operator (look up matrix exponential for example).

Answer (score 3):

Even if we restrict to analytic transformation(not to mention bigger spaces, such as smooth transformations, or continous transformations) , this cannot be achieved for any $n$, since the space of transformations in this case is infinite dimensional, u can see this by considering the following (linearly independent) family : $f_{n, m} (x, y) =x^{m} y^{n} $